# Cakephp how to display a particular record when searched using one field

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I am new to cakephp.

I have two table related to each other (student and payment_detail). 
students hasMany paymentDetails and 
paymentDetails belongTo student.

I have a search view:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Student.roll_no', array('label' => __('Roll No'))); ?> 
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('View')); ?>
```

view method in controller:

```
public function view(){ 
        if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
            $this->request->data; 
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'detailedview'));                   
        }
}
```

when I click the view button it redirects me to detailedview. So my problem here is how to create detailedview method for controller to retrieve all the fields in a record related to particular roll_no.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

1) Change your view function to:

```
public function view( $id=null ){ 
        if ($this->request->is('post')) { 
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'detailedview', $id));
        }
}
```

2) add the following function in your controller:

```
public function detailedview( $id=null ) {
....
}
```

Before you do that I recommend reading the documentation again and do the Blog tutorial.